# Determining number of vertices of selected object in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, features, select, vertices, count

How can I determine how many vertices/nodes a selected feature has in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`num_points($geometry)`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#num-points) returns the number of vertices of the current feature.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the following script in QGIS Python Editor. Select a layer, run the script and select a feature.

```py
def n_vertices(selected, _, __):
    n = len(selected)
    
    if n == 1:
        g = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()[0].geometry()
        print(len([v for v in g.vertices()]))
    elif n > 1:
        print("Select only one feature")
        
iface.activeLayer().selectionChanged.connect(n_vertices)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try using the [image: icon]["Identify Features"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#identify) tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) from the Attributes Toolbar.

Click on the target feature and check the *(Derived)* tab, where you may see the **'Vertices'** attribute

[image: result]