# Calculating polygon area in QGIS without adding new field

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, area, measurements

Is it possible in QGIS to quickly calculate the area of a polygon using a Processing tool, plugin, script without adding attributes or creating a new layer?

Something launching the results window or even a point and click feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I personally find the identify tool sometimes too clunky. Here another approach:

To show the area for a polygon without using an additional field, you can just use a formula for a label with the `$area` function, e.g.:

```
round($area/10000,1)
```

will give you the area of the features in hectares.

As you just want to see the area when pointing/clicking, you could add

```
CASE
WHEN  is_selected() THEN round($area/10000,1)
END
```

When you now use the **select tool**  pointing on a polygon, it will show the area label.
[image]

In case your polygons already have a label based on some field(s), you can extend the formula with an ELSE statement to switch between normal view and selected view:

```
CASE
WHEN  is_selected() is FALSE THEN "id"
ELSE round($area/10000,1)
END
```

[image]

Please mind that I never have used this approach myself, I just came up with this idea while reading your question.

Comment: I tried both methods and it worked perfectly, an elegant solution.

Answer (score 10):

The identify tool does offer you this information.

Click any feature, then expand the topmost dropdown menu. Here all basic geometric information is hidden, incl. the area and circumfence.

[image]

Comment: This is the kind of solution I was looking for, definitely. Some of the answers below are more helpful, but this is what I had in my mind for a quick check.

Answer (score 10):

Create a label with the expressin `$area` (I should have used `round($area)`):

[image]

Comment: Most obvious and easy option.

Answer (score 4):

Also possible by means of PyQGIS.

```py
def feature_area(selected, _, __):
    n = len(selected)
    
    if n == 1:
        g = iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()[0].geometry()
        print("The area of selected feature is " + '{:0,.2f}'.format(g.area()) + " m²")
        
    elif n > 1:
        print("Select only one feature")

iface.activeLayer().selectionChanged.connect(feature_area)
```

[image: result]

Inspiration was found in: [Determining number of vertices of selected object in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387717/determining-number-of-vertices-of-selected-object-in-qgis-3)

Answer (score 4):

Another option is using the [image: display_icon]["Display"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#display-properties) through `RMC > Properties > Display`.

[image: Display]

Paste the following expression `format_number($area,2,'de')` into the *'Display Name'* and press <kbd>Apply</kbd>.

*Note:* I made it in very intuitive way, more sophisticated output can be achieved via the *'HTML Map Tip'*.

After hover over the feature and get the output

[image: result]